# Explanation of mongo query with OR condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have this data in my db

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c89da093180684aba34c5b7"), "name" : "Allen", "age" : 24, "nicknames" : [ "kanky" ], "siblings" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c89da4b3180684aba34c5b8"), "name" : "Sonata", "age" : "30" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c89da8f3180684aba34c5b9"), "name" : "Kaushik", "age" : "20" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c89da8f3180684aba34c5ba"), "name" : "Stuart", "age" : "24" }
{ "_id" : "5c89da093180684aba34c5b7", "name" : "Allen", "age" : 24 }
```

When I run this query `db.people.find({$or: [{name:"Allen"}, {age:24}]})`, it doesn't give the entry with `name : Stuart` which has `age : 24`.

But if I run this query `db.people.find({$or: [{name:"Stuart"}, {age:24}]})`, it works as intended.

Can anyone explain how does this work? I am starting with mongodb, so mightbe a very basic question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different schema types for age in different documents. For Allen you are using a number data type for age and for Stuart you are using a string to store age. I think thats the problem.

Try running this:-

```
db.people.find({$or: [{name:"Allen"}, {age: "24" }]})
```

You will get Stuart with this query. I don't see anything else wrong here except for different data types.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. 

Do you know how even though if I pass age as string in the query, it returns the entry for the numbers also where the reverse is not true ?

Comment: I don't think it does that. Please try running the query with only age set to string 24 and it should not return Allen

Comment: My bad. It doesn't. I was being careless and missed the OR condition. 

Thank you for your help.